# Getting 8-bit individual addresses of uint16_t with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

The address space on my device is 8 bit.  I have a 16 bit unsigned integer.  I'd like to be able to use pointers to individually extract the data at the two registers which make up the 16 bit int.

```
uint16_t num = 12345;
uint8_t *ptr1;
uint8_t *ptr2;
```

Thanks for the help, pointers have been confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the address of the 16 bit variable and cast it to a pointer to `uint8_t`, then add the necessary offset.

```
uint16_t num = 12345;
uint8_t *ptr1 = ((uint8_t *)&num);
uint8_t *ptr2 = ((uint8_t *)&num) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know if there would have been a way to do this without the type casting?

Comment: It would overflow and doesn't make sense for a single address. In an array it would take the address of the next element

Comment: @John Pointer addition would increment or decrement based on the type it's pointer is pointing to. Without typecasting, your num is of 16 bit type and when you would do &num + 1, it would  point to 16 bits passed &num.

Answer (score 1):

> [if there would have been a way to do this without the type casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071093/getting-8-bit-individual-addresses-of-uint16-t-with-pointers#comment102537877_58071131)

Cast-less solution: use a `union`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef struct my_struct {
  uint8_t var1;
  uint8_t var2;
} my_struct;

int main(void) {
  uint16_t num = 12345;

  union {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint8_t u8[2];
  } x = {.u16 = num};

  uint8_t *ptr1 = &x.u8[0];
  uint8_t *ptr2 = &x.u8[1];

  printf("num x%04X\n", num);
  printf("*ptr1 x%02X\n", *ptr1);
  printf("*ptr2 x%02X\n", *ptr2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
num x3039
*ptr1 x39
*ptr2 x30
```